# How to remap the Context Menu key to the Super key

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xkb

This keyboard has only one super key, so I want to remap the menu key to make up for that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `xev` to find the keycode for the key you want to remap. For example if I press <kbd>Menu</kbd> key it tells me that that is **keycode 135**.

Next in my `~/.xmodmaprc` file, I add a line like this:

```
keycode 135 = Super_R
```

... to make it the right hand windows key. Then all that remains is to activate the key remaps. This usually happens automatically on login to your x session, but if your Desktop Environment doesn't do that you can run it manually as `xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc` from a command line or whatever script gets run when you login.

Comment: The only real problem with xmodmap is, when you switch layouts. You have to execute xmodmap again.

Comment: I just tried exactly this, and I do not get any event for the menu key. I use Xfce4 maybe that's the reason, but I can't map the menu key to anything useful.

Comment: @arne no event shows in `xev`? Do all the other keys show events?

Comment: @Caleb yes all other keys show events. But for me it is solved now. I found out, that when I do `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` from `.xinitrc`, as it is described in arch wiki, it does work. Just the preview with xmodmap when I am already logged in doesn't work.

Comment: Or `$ xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = Meta_L"` for a quick fix.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what system you use, but if it is quite modern login as root, go to

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes
```

Copy (make a backup) `evdev` file. Edit it. Find the line with Menu Key and change its alias to super key (left or right) e.g. change

```
alias <MENU> = <COMP>;
```

to

```
alias <MENU> = <SUPR>;
```

Logout, login (`X11` has to be restarted), enjoy your new keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

This does the trick:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Menu = Super_R"
```

Answer (score -1):

for gnome-shell, one just needs to edit this file: */usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc*. and then reboot.

Comment: While this may be a solution to the OPs problem, to make your answer actually helpful you should add an example, and perhaps explaning the details.