# Key binding of the Menu Key

Tags: key-mapping, fluxbox

I have the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key that I don't use. It's right under my thumb when I use the arrows... So I wanted to map it to the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. *(mostly because of its important use in vim)*

I've been looking into the [fluxbox wiki](http://fluxbox-wiki.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts) for key bindings, but I have not found what I'm searching.

I have tried to add in my `.fluxbox/keys`

```
135 :118
```

or

```
135 :Insert
```

But both doesn't seem to work. Is it possible with fluxbox ?

I am also wondering if the `BindKey <key><value>: <action>               #creates an "on the fly" keycommand` can do the job... but I don't really understand what it does...

The answer to [How to remap the Context Menu key to the Super key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13369/how-to-remap-the-context-menu-key-to-the-super-key) indicates to modify .xmodmaprc

Maybe that's what should I do, but I don't know how to convert `keycode 135 = Super_R` so at it works like Insert instead of Super_R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keys-file of fluxbox does not map keys to other keys; it maps keys to fluxbox-actions. So, you need something that maps keys to keys: [`man xmodmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap).

```
 xmodmap - utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings in X
```

examples:

```
 $> xmodmap -e "keysym Menu = Insert"
 $> xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = Insert"
```